# Group of infinite sequences of elements in a given finite group

Tags: group-theory

Could you tell me why each element of a group of infinite sequences of elements in a given finite group has finite order?

Comment: it would help if you actually describe the group of infinite sequences of elements in a given finite group. What is the group operation?

Comment: That's just it. I don't know what the operation is. Could it be $(a_1, a_2, a_3, ...)(b_1, b_2, b_3, ...) = (a_1 * b_1, a_2 * b_2, ...)$?

Comment: @Andrew It could. My answer assumes that the operation is exactly like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because a finite group $G$ has finite [exponent](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_of_a_group). In other words, not only does every element $x \in G$ have finite order, but also there is a number $n$ such that $x^n=1$ for all $x \in G$ simultaneously.

Comment: Could you tell me more specifically, how to prove that $(a_1 * b_1, a_2 * b_2, ...)$ has a finite order. Is saying that there exists $n$ such that $(ab)^n = 1$ is justification enough?

Comment: There exists $n$ that $x^n=1$ for all $x$, and all the more $a_i^n = 1$ for any sequence $(a_1, a_2, \ldots)$ and for all indexes $i$.

Comment: I see that now. Thank you.